# Android App keeps crashing on Build. Debugger only shows little

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

I have a simple application with two activities. A Connection Activity that establishes a Bluetooth connection; and a PollTaker Activity that gets a message and manipulates the data from there.

The manifest is like so: http://pastebin.com/xFs3AdrF

When the app starts it should begin with a Connection activity that is also the default and load up the following content view: http://pastebin.com/KCDeAki1

I went and checked previous questions and this was the closest I could find: [New app crashing on start-up, debug not helping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640026/new-app-crashing-on-start-up-debug-not-helping)

However I have my components being set AFTER I call setContentView() in onCreate. Am I misunderstanding something or did I incorrectly implement this?

Code for my Connection activity: http://pastebin.com/GcZyDayc

EDIT: Forgot to mention I had my own debug logs written and all that shows up is the Log in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

After testing it turned out to be something with my Android SDK Files with BT. As soon as I commented out the

```
btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
CheckBTState();
```

in my connection class my app loaded up the first page. However this confuses me since the test app I based this on uses the same Adapter Test to enable it at start with no problems. Probably incorrectly loaded SDK files.

EDIT: Newbie Developer mistake. I forgot to add the user permissions for BT in my manifest. (Doh...)